# Overuse internet connection with app

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, cordova

I am creating android application, using the PhoneGap platform. I have tested the use of resources by the application and I noticed that uses a lot of free 3G. In comparison to an application such as whatsapp, using too much connection.
My app is a chat, and I use javascript to make requests to refresh messages. Following the javascript that takes care of this:

```
var refreshShout = setInterval(app.ajaxFunction, 1000);    
[...]
ajaxFunction: function () {
        var shoutbase = $('.shoutbox');
        if (shoutbase) {
            $.get('http://edonetwork.altervista.org/Magnitude/log.php', function (data) {})
        .done(function(data) {
            $(shoutbase).html(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $(shoutbase).html('<div class="alert-internet">Ops... Occorre una connessione ad internet per usufruire dell\'App!</div>');
        });
        }
}
```

In log.php page there are all existing messages taken with MYSQL query from the database of altervista.
Below is the query that is executed:

```
$dati=mysql_query("   SELECT * FROM `Shoutbox` ORDER BY `Shoutbox`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30   ");
```

How can I limit the use of the internet? As currently is excessive! But I think all chat app continue to make requests but why are more performant?

Thank you.

Comment: Your query appears to always be returning 30 records. I would expect the app to remember the highest `ID` it has been given - and only request higher `ID` numbers on subsequent requests. This way only new messages will be returned to the app - reducing the internet usage to the minimum possible.

Comment: Refreshing every second with a large amount of JSON is going to be murderously bad. What about using WebSockets? Also, are you really sure you want to be using the really old `mysql_query` interface?

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand. Do you mean that every request I check if the previous ID is less than a next query?

Comment: @tadman: Could you briefly introduce WebSockets? For queries, I can easily upgrade to mysqli. (Change something in the costs of the internet and / or speed?)

Comment: Websockets are a persistent connection you can send events over instead of having to repeatedly poll. An example implementation in PHP is [Ratchet](http://socketo.me), though as a point of comparison NodeJS does a spectacular job of this sort of thing. Basically you maintain a light-weight connection to the clients you can push data over when you need to, using near-zero bandwidth when you don't.